# When I import Google`s UniversalMusicPlayer to my android studio, it crashed

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a newcomer who want to learn android.My friend suggested me to read the code of that player,but  when I imported the project and compiled it,it crashed...

> 12-22 20:58:07.755 4870-4870/com.example.android.uamp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.example.android.uamp, PID: 4870 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable
>   to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.android.uamp/com.example.android.uamp.ui.MusicPlayerActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza:
>   No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is
>   0. at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2448)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:163) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1371)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5595) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) Caused
>   by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found.
>   Local version is 0 and remote version is 0. at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni.zzbg(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni.zza(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.example.android.uamp.ui.ActionBarCastActivity.onCreate(ActionBarCastActivity.java:141)
>   at
>   com.example.android.uamp.ui.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:49)
>   at
>   com.example.android.uamp.ui.MusicPlayerActivity.onCreate(MusicPlayerActivity.java:57)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:163)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1371) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5595)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>   Caused by: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable
>   module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0. at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb.zza(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni.zzbg(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni.zza(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.example.android.uamp.ui.ActionBarCastActivity.onCreate(ActionBarCastActivity.java:141)
>   at
>   com.example.android.uamp.ui.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:49)
>   at
>   com.example.android.uamp.ui.MusicPlayerActivity.onCreate(MusicPlayerActivity.java:57)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:163)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1371) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5595)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Well,when I searched for answers,the responses were not useful...
And if you have some wonderful open source project to recommend ,hope you can tell me.Thx.
Sorry for my poor english...

Comment: have you made sure you've declared any new Activities in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your google play service of device.

You can see this [Bug report](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/issues/97) which already has been addressed

and possibility you will have to update your `gcm` dependency then appropriate modifications of code will also required mean the deprecated methods will be needed to replaced with new one in the project for e.g `GoogleApiAvailability` to register token etc so also make sure you are using the latest `gcm` dependency in your project